# Angular 4 - ouline all components and decorate with name

Tags: angular

I would like to select all Angular components and add custom CSS style (border) and append div with component name.

Is there a way to write an angular `directive` or use `@ViewChildren` or other way to achieve that?

Issues:

1. select all components
2. get component name in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I want is solved by [Augury](https://augury.angular.io/) Chrome extension:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your scenario matches then try like this

```
in ts
isselect = false;

<button (click)="isselect=true"></button>


<div [ngClass]="{'classname':isselect === true}">
    <component1></component1>
</div>
<div [ngClass]="{'classname':isselect === true}">
    <component2></component2>
</div>
<div [ngClass]="{'classname':isselect === true}">
    <component2></component2>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to do it without modifying HTML structure. This approach would require to wrap all existing components inside a div.

Comment: even if you create any custom attibute directive, to apply directive to the compoents then also you should follow above approach